# QMultimedia not working in Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtquick2

I've made a simple recorder using Qt Quick in order to make a multi platform application ( Android, IOS, Desktop).

I've used the Qt Multimedia library to record and play sounds. It worked very well in Desktop but when I deploy it on Android I'm still able to record but when I hit play, it returns

> ResourceError

and the error message is

> "Attempting to play invalid resource"

Please can you help me? Which codec should I use ?

Comment: Any part of code of your simple recorder so we could help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i changed the codec and the container format and point the output to /storage/Music and it worked, but i want to record as wav...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add multimedia library like below?

```
QT += qml quick widgets multimedia
```

I don't know why, but I encountered the same problem when using QML Audio.

It works on OSX without 'multimedia', but I needed it on Android.

I hope these can help you.

Comment: I've already done it and it didn't work, i changed the codec and container format to wav and the output location to Storage/Music and it worked.

Comment: But i need to record as wav !